# Uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability-theory

A point is chosen at random on a line of length L. What is  the probability that the ratio of the shorter to the longer segment is less than 1/4?

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible meanings of "at random." We assume that the location of the point is chosen **uniformly** in the interval $[0,L]$.

The ratio is exactly $\frac{1}{4}$ if the point of division is at $\frac{L}{5}$ or $L-\frac{L}{5}$, and is less than $\frac{1}{4}$ if  the point of division is $\lt \frac{L}{5}$ or $\gt L-\frac{L}{5}$. The combined length of the two intervals $[0,\frac{L}{5}]$ and $[L-\frac{L}{5},L]$ is $\frac{2L}{5}$, It follows that the  required probability is $\frac{2L/5}{L}$, that is, $\frac{2}{5}$.